# How to use multiple session.setAttribute to fetch row value from sql database?

Tags: javascript, sql

I am trying to fetch row value on jsp page textox. I have used **value="${sessionScope.zfid}"** then value is fetched but when I used **value="${sessionScope.firstname}"** then no value fetched. I fetched one value(zfid) but not able to do for other textboxes. Please see below code and suggest me where I am getting wrong.

**This is index.jsp**

```html
<tr>
<td>Z id</td>
<td>
<input type="text" required="" name="zid"  value="${sessionScope.zfid}" readonly/> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td>
<input type="text" required="" name="firstname" value="${sessionScope.firstname}"/>
</td>
</tr>
```

**This is loginscript.jsp**

```html
<%
String zfid = request.getParameter("zid"); 
String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms", "root", "");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs;
rs = st.executeQuery("select * from dmsmembers where zid='" + zfid + "' and pass='" + pwd + "'");
if (rs.next()) {
   session.setAttribute("zfid", zfid);
   session.setAttribute("firstname", firstname);
   //out.println("welcome " + userid);
   //out.println("<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");
   response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
} 
else {
   out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
   out.println("alert('Invalid username or password');");
   out.println("location='loginJSP.jsp';");
   out.println("</script>");
}
%>
```

This is uploadservlet.java class

```html
public class UploadServletClass extends HttpServlet{
    PrintWriter out = null;
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    HttpSession session = null;
    
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException{
        response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
        try{
            out = response.getWriter();
            session = request.getSession(false);
            String folderName = "allfiles";
            
            ...
            
            
           if(counter > 0){
                    String msg = "Successfully uploaded " + counter + " file(s).";
                    request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
                    System.out.println(msg);
                    session.setAttribute("filename", fileName);
                }
       }
       
}
```

Comment: where do you store session. whats in session variable?

Comment: @MrKhan I have UploadServlet class in that class I used session.

Comment: I have index.jsp page. In that I want to fetch value from sql table to jsp textbox. I fetched zfid but I am failed to fetch firstname. How to do it?

Comment: if (rs.next()) { after this line console.log(res) and see the output

Comment: when I did View page source then I got <input type="text" required="" name="zid"  value="z0009289" readonly/>  and this <input type="text" required="" name="firstname" value=""/>